# Javascript Google Map not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm new to Google Maps api and its library. I wonder why I'm not seeing the map in my page.

This is the code:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
    <script>
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(-0.179041, -78.499211);
        console.log(latlong);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlong,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('city_map'),
                mapOptions);
        console.log(map);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom());

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlong,
            map: map,
            title: "Test"
        });
</script>
```

You see I'm `console.logging` the `latlong` and the `map`, they look fine.. anyway, I hope it is not something extremely obvious.

Comment: Could you please post your `HTML` code for map?

Comment: Where is your code in the page? Is it at the end of the body (after the HTML has rendered)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have height and width attached to the div, thats why. Check out this fiddle.

```
#city_map{
 min-height:300px;
 min-width:300px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dm7j7494/1/

Comment: The problem is just as likely to be the lack of waiting for the page 'load' event.

Comment: @alejoss, glad to help :)